# MYSQL select and update keeps finding more rows, thought data is static

Tags: mysql

I am running a query that is rolling up data from large INNODB table- 40 million records. The query is pulling a single day, about 150k records and then produces about 500 rows.

However if I run the query, in the resulting tables, where it is to insert the rows, not all the rows are written to the table.

I find that I need to run the same query with the same date at least 10 times before no new data is written to the result table.

The result table is also INNODB, but then changed it to MYISAM - still getting the same effect.

I am not a DB expert - so I feel like I throwing paint on the wall to see what sticks.

Here is the query...

```
set autocommit=1;
INSERT INTO reportscanhistory (activdate,custid,taskid,scanct,garmtypeid) 
SELECT activdate,customer,task,qty,garmtypeid 
FROM (SELECT activdate,customer,objecthistory.task,COUNT(DISTINCT objectid) AS qty,objects.garmtypeid 
  FROM objecthistory 
  LEFT JOIN objects ON objects.id = objecthistory.objectid  WHERE objects.garmtypeid>0 AND activdate=DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()),INTERVAL 1 DAY)
  GROUP BY activdate,customer,objects.garmtypeid) AS t 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE scanct =t.qty;
```

Comment: did you verify that all insertions should actually take place?
What did the DB say when you executed the queries? Where there exceptions?  

Are you sure that DATE is in same timezone as you expecT?

Comment: Incidentally `LEFT JOIN x... WHERE x =...` is the same as `INNER JOIN x`